# Why my class based logout view doesn't work?

Tags: django

I'm trying to write a logout view that returns the main page of my application.
The result is the that home page is called correctly, but the user is not logged out. Why does the logout not work correctly?

views.py

```
class BaseView(View):
    left_menu_bar = get_categories()  # not importatn here
    context = {'left_menu_bar': left_menu_bar, 'username': ''}
    template_name = ''
    extra_context = {}
    for element in extra_context:
        context[element] = extra_context[element]

    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            username = request.user.username
            self.context['username'] = username
        return render(request, 'buybook/' + self.template_name, self.context)


class Main(BaseView):
    template_name = 'main.html'


class LogOut(View):
    def get(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('buybook:main'))
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'buybook'

urlpatterns = [
        #...
        path('', views.Main.as_view(), name='main'),
        path('logout', views.LogOut.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

and templates:
base.html

```
<html>
{%if username%}
  Your nickname is <b>{{username}}</b>
<a href='{%url 'buybook:logout' %}'> log me out</a>
<br><br>
{%else%}
  You're not logged in<br>
  <a href='{%url 'buybook:loginpanel' %}'>login</a><br>
  <a href='{%url 'buybook:registrationpanel' %}'>create an account</a>
{%endif%}

{%block books %}
{%endblock%}
</html>
```

main.html

```
<html>
{% extends 'buybook/base.html' %}

{% block books %}
  <h1>Welcom</h1>
  <p>
    etc.
  </p>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

I've created registration and login views before and they work correctly, so I don't paste the code for these views. Only LogOut view is a problem.

Comment: Are you sure you call the correct `logout` function? What function did you import? Are you sure you did not override the reference (by defining another class/function/... with the same name)?

Comment: I don't know what you think all that "extra_context" logic is doing, but I guarantee it is not doing that.

Comment: 1. I use this function: from django.contrib.auth import logout. I don't use this name anywhere else. 2. "extra_context" is a dictionary that can be overwritten by an derived class if I want to add some new context. Isn't it a good approach?